# sorting JSON table with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have this simple JSON table where the elements needs to be sorted in alpabetical order by value and the other alpabetical order by name. Could someone give me and example how would i do it so i can understand it?

```
{

  "sortingTask": [

      {"sortAlpabeticallyByValue": [

      {"string":"äää"},

      {"string":"bee"},

      {"string":"aaa"},

      {"string":"öoöo"},

      {"string":"OöOö"},   

  ]},

      {"sortAlpabeticallyByName": [

      {"stringB":"testi1"},

      {"stringÄ":"testi2"},

      {"stringA":"testi3"}

  ]},

  {"sortAlpabetically": [

      "äää","bee","baa"

  ]}

  ]

}
```

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: @HemantRajpoot That comment is wrong! No need to parse a JSON. It's an object so you can sort it by reading the properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom sort method using switch case. For comparison between two words you can use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
var data = { "sortingTask": [ {"sortAlpabeticallyByValue": [ {"string":"äää"}, {"string":"bee"}, {"string":"aaa"}, {"string":"öoöo"}, {"string":"OöOö"}, ]}, {"sortAlpabeticallyByName": [{"stringB":"testi1"}, {"stringÄ":"testi2"}, {"stringA":"testi3"} ]}, {"sortAlpabetically":[ "äää","bee","baa" ]}]};

data.sortingTask.forEach(function(obj){
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
    switch(k){
      case 'sortAlpabeticallyByValue' :
        obj[k].sort(function(a,b){
          return a.string.localeCompare(b.string, undefined, { sensitivity: 'variant' });
        });
        break;
       case 'sortAlpabetically':
        obj[k].sort(function(a,b){
          return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {sensitivity: 'variant'});
        });
        break;
       case 'sortAlpabeticallyByName':
        obj[k].sort(function(a,b){
          return Object.keys(a)[0].localeCompare(Object.keys(b)[0]);
        });
        break;
    }
  });
});
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```